# (Magento 2) Configurable product price doesn't change

Tags: magento2, product, price

Version : Magento 2.3.2
Theme : Cleversoft

Hello,
I have a product with it's variations (depending on the delivery).

On my product page, I have my button for chose the delivery option, but the price doesn't change (only on the view, because it's adding the good price in the cart).

I have try to modify several files (like the 'tier_price' or 'renderer' or 'final price' files).

If someone have an idea, a solution or whatever that could help me... It will be very nice.

Comment: Have you modified the template for price ?

Comment: Concerning my display of the main price, I have not modified anything, the basic displayed price is the price of the first variation.

I also display it in a second way, in a table where the prices are indicated according to the quantity.

When I click on my buttons to change the delivery mode, it should change the price of my product as well as the values in the tables.

PS: to create the table I modified the'tier_price' file which displayed sentences (ex: "Buy X for X€ and save XX%") by adding html tags <tr> and <td>.